# php - how to show all images in a dir created on selected day

Tags: php, html

I have a camera that uploads a picute every second to my ftp server. (website)
All those pictures are stored into one dir.

What I want is to show all the pictures made on one particular date.

I have a script that displays ALL the pictures in the dir:

```
<?php 
$dirname = "./";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
foreach($images as $image) {
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}
?>
```

The date the created file is recorded when I open filezilla but I dont know how to get that information into php.

what I'm trying to make is an input script where I can select:

```
[Year: ****] [mo: **] [Day: **]
```

and then I get a list of all the pictures taken that particular date.

Comment: You already asked the same question earlier.

Comment: Why don't you store them in separate folders, named after the dates..

Comment: i know but i think this method is better becous it has nothing to do with the file name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filemtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) to get the file modified time,

`$filename = 'somefile.txt';`

`if (file_exists($filename)) { echo "$filename was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename)); }`